# Finding Apps on my iPhone

Tags: iphone

Where are downloaded apps located on my iPhone?  I went to download the Prisma App and the download page indicated that it was installed. Now I want to use the App but do not know how to find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can launch an app on an iPhone multiple ways. A few of them are:

**1.** Swipe left (or right) until you are on the screen of the desired app. Then simply tap the image that is located above the name of the app and the application should launch.

**2.** Use spotlight search: To use spotlight search simply pull the screen down when you are on the home screen of your iPhone. Then simply type on the name of the desired app and it should appear. Then tap the image above the name of the app and it should launch

**3.** Siri: To use Siri to launch a app hold down on your phone's home button. Your phone should vibrate and then you should say: "Launch (the name of the desired app)". Then the app should launch.

These are a few of the basic ways to launch a app. There are other ways but they get more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Pull the screen down shortly like if you would like to scroll it down and on top of it the search field should appear. Start typing name of an app, i.e. Prisma and it should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Swipe along the home screen and you should find it on the last page.

Comment: We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment:      